# Meaning of "no more than a lie"

Tags: meaning

What does Trump mean by saying, *"Comey's testimony ... is no more than a lie"* in the following context?

> The President's response could signal that he is convinced he has done nothing wrong and that Comey's testimony before the Senate Intelligence Committee on Thursday is no more than a lie.

- Full article on [CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/09/politics/trump-bets-theres-no-smoking-gun-in-comey-case/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

An emphasizing phrase.  The meaning is "nothing other than a lie," or "a lie and nothing else," or something similar.  Simply a case of adding the vaguely meaningful "no more than" to "a lie."  Normal people would more likely say, if they wanted to indicate emphasis, "a plain lie" or "a lie pure and simple."

Comment: There is another common usage and perhaps the intended meaning in this case.  Often, "no more than a lie" isn't used so much for emphasis as dismissal.  It's saying that if there is anything truthful there, it's immaterial or a distraction; the substantive and important part is a lie. You can dismiss the whole thing as a lie because anything that isn't a lie is irrelevant filler.  It can also have a meaning that what was said had a truthful ring but was misleading or a distortion of the truth, so it was effectively a lie.